# My function doesn't return full data range. What is the syntax of getRange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm bulding a webApp w/ Google App Scripts. In my main .gs file, I'm trying to get & return the values from a data range in my connected sheet. My function below seems to only return the values for column 1 in the range when it has 4 columns.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function loadBoats(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("* myspreadSheet url*");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("DB1.vessels");
  var boats = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1:D12").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  Logger.log(boats);
  return boats;

}
```

Picture for logs:

[image]

**Additionally:**

I don't understand the structure of the first .getRange() method w/ 4 parameters. This is the YT link I am following along w/ - [Youtube tutorial on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXrOyTBjdjE)

Answer (score 2):

The range is finally `A1:A12` as specified by the outter `getRange`.

```js
ws.getRange("A1:D12").getDataRegion().getLastRow()
// 12

ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1:D12").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1)
// getRange(1,1,12,1) -> equivalent to 'A1:A12'
```

---

You should simply call `ws.getRange("A1:D12").getValues();`.

#### Reference:

[getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Thanks man, that was a big help!

Also found the '.getRange (a,b,c,d)' method definition here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting 1 column is because you put **1** in the **4th parameter** of your [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) function. The **4th parameter** determines how many columns you want to retrieve starting from the **2nd parameter**.

Here is the definition of each parameter in `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`:

> - row    Integer The starting row index of the range; row indexing starts with 1.
> - column Integer The starting column index of the range; column indexing starts with 1.
> - numRows    Integer The number of rows to return.
> - numColumns Integer The number of columns to return.

### Example:

**getRange(1,1,12,4)**

- Row starts at 1
- Column Starts at A
- Add 12 rows starting 1
- Add 4 columns starting from A

The result range in A1 notation is **A1:D12**

### Solution:

In your code, since you already knew how many rows to retrieve **(A1:D12) or 12** rows and you want 4 columns, just change your code to `var boats = ws.getRange(1,1,12,4).getValues();`

Comment: Thanks man, that was a big help!

Also found the '.getRange (a,b,c,d)' method definition here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns